# connect PHP with postgreSQL8.3

Tags: php, postgresql, connection

I was trying to connect my PHP page to PostgreSQL, but it's not working. The code which I have tried is given below:

```
<?php

 $connection = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=mydb user=postgres password=pgsql"); 

 if (!$connection)
 { 
   echo "Couldn't make a connection!"; 
 } 

?>
```

During the time of installation, the system asked me for a password and I had gives as `pgsql`. My database name is "mydb". Somebody please help me.

Thanks and regards.

tismon

Comment: @tismon; do you get any error message ?

Comment: A db connection failure should result in a PHP warning with an error message. If it's not printed on the page, check your error log and post the error message here.

Answer (score 1):

I advice you to take a look at [`pg_last_error`](http://fr.php.net/pg_last_error), it would give you valuable info on what is going wrong

i.e.

```
if(!$connection){
 die(pg_last_error($connection));
}
```

Comment: i didnt get any error message even it doesnot printing the other simple echo after the connection string :(

Comment: like pointed by max you should have something in apache log, if you have shell access to the server you can try to use `psql` and see if you can connect like expected.

Answer (score 1):

The error message i got after troubleshooting is

"pgsql module unavailable"

I set the

extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
 extension=php_pgsql.dll

and
extension_dir = "C:\php\ext"

in the php.ini file.But it was of no use.

I use postgresql 8.3 and php 5.2.12 threadsafe with apache 2.2 in win xp...

any help will be deeply appreciated..

Tismon

Answer (score 1):

its solved.. the problem is with the php version. i had installed php5.2.6 and replced the pgsql.dll extension with that of php5.2.5

Thanks a lot VolkerK,RageZ and Max S

regards

tismon

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [pgsql module isn't installed/loaded](http://docs.php.net/pgsql.installation)?

```
<?php
echo "<pre>If this line isn't printed you have a parse error in your script</pre>\n"; flush();
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', true);    
extension_loaded('pgsql') || die('pgsql module unavailable');


$connection = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=mydb user=postgres password=pgsql"); 
if (!$connection) { 
  echo "Couldn't make a connection! ". pg_last_error(); 
}
else {
  echo 'connected to server';
}
flush();
?>
```